# NativeScript animation just firing once

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I have a NativeScript project which contains a ListView. I used its event "onItemTap" and this is the function I wrote:

```
   onItemTap(args){
      let clicked = args.view.bindingContext;
      let fav = this.page.getViewById("star-"+clicked.id);
      fav.animate({
          rotate: 360,
          duration: 1000
      });

    }
```

Basically I'm retrieving the item I clicked, inside the item there is a label which has the id `"star-N"` [N is the intex of the item] and I'm animating it.
It works fine, the problem is that **it just works once**! From the second tap, it animates no more. The console isn't returning any errors. I'm using my Android device to debug it.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently after the rotation, the "rotate" property of the element isn't reset to its initial value. This means that in the first tap your rotate property goes from 0 => 360  and then on the second tap from 360 => 360 so no animation occurs.

Not sure if it is really intended to be like this but you can always manually set the rotate property to 0 once the animation is done:

```
onItemTap(args) {
    let clicked = args.view.bindingContext;
    let fav = this.page.getViewById("star-"+clicked.id);
    fav.animate({
        rotate: 360,
        duration: 1000
    }).then(() => fav.rotate = 0);
}
```

Comment: Holy crap, I thought that the "animate" method affected the element just temporarily! I didn't think that it could have set the "rotate" property to 360! Thank you! Could you tell me where are the properties of the view listed in the NativeScript docs?